# FreeBSD 9.0 install NOT configuring ports

Tags: freebsd, bsd-ports, configuration

We have a new FreeBSD 9.0-RELEASE with a ports tree generated via portsnap and none of the ports perform `make config`.

To some degree it is behaving as though `BATCH=yes` was set. However, that variable does not appear in `/etc/make.conf` (which is actually blank); nor is it set in the environment. `make -V BATCH` returns blank. `make config` pulls up the dialog screens and then happily writes options out to `/var/db/ports/[whatever]/options`; but simply running `make` (or using `portmaster`) skips the config process and writes nothing out to `/var/db/ports`.

What on earth is happening?

Comment: During install did you populate the ports tree? If not you can rerun the sysinstall or download the tarball and extract it. See http://www.freebsd.org/ports/installing.html

Comment: Nah. We always skip that step and run 'portsnap fetch extract' instead. By the time we get our hands on an ISO, the ports tree on the disc is already old.

Comment: go to a port `dir` and run `make config`. Does it come up with a configuration window?

Comment: This can be other files besides your environment, page through /etc/make.conf or post it anywhere.